# C lang array length variable got changed

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to find why the `positiveNum` is changed. I found the place where it got changed, but have no clue why this happened.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct TernaryGroup {
  int size;
  int groupList[][3];
} TernaryGroup;

int test(int num) {
  int positiveNum = num + 1;
  TernaryGroup ternaryGroups[positiveNum];
  for (int index = 0; index < positiveNum; index++) {
    ternaryGroups[index].size = 0;
  }
  for (int aIndex = 1; aIndex < positiveNum; aIndex++) {
    for (int bIndex = aIndex + 1; bIndex < positiveNum; bIndex++) {
      for (int cIndex = bIndex + 1; cIndex < positiveNum; cIndex++) {
        int isUnsafeTernary = (2 * (bIndex - aIndex)) == (cIndex - bIndex);
        if (!isUnsafeTernary) {
          continue;
        }
        int newTernary[3] = {aIndex, bIndex, cIndex};

        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
          int groupName = newTernary[index];
          int curGroupSize = ternaryGroups[groupName].size;
          // positiveNum is changed by these lines, but I don't know why
          ternaryGroups[groupName].groupList[curGroupSize][0] = aIndex;
          ternaryGroups[groupName].groupList[curGroupSize][1] = bIndex;
          ternaryGroups[groupName].groupList[curGroupSize][2] = cIndex;

          ternaryGroups[groupName].size++;
        }
        printf("newTernary %d %d %d\n", aIndex, bIndex, cIndex);
        printf("why positiveNum %d is not 7 \n", positiveNum);
      }
    }
  }

  return num;
}
int main() {
  test(6);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TernaryGroup` structure ends with a flexible array member, `int groupList[][3];`. No space is reserved for this member, and the structure should never be used in an array.

`TernaryGroup ternaryGroups[positiveNum];` defines an array of `ternaryGroups`. If your compiler did not issue a warning about this, enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

When later code tries to use the `groupList` members of the elements in this array, they attempt to access undefined elements of the arrays.

You cannot use this structure to hold data the way you want. You must redesign the program either to use separately allocated `TernaryGroup` structures, each allocated with the space it needs for its flexible array member, or you must redesign the structure so the `groupList` member is not a flexible array member. It could be a pointer to memory elsewhere, which you must similarly allocate.